# Why can't I directly return reference to a pointer from a function returning a pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, return

In C++, this code does not compile:

```
double* value() {
    return nullptr;
}

double*& function() {
    return value();
}
```

`Error: Non-const lvalue reference to type 'double *' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'double *'`

However, this code does compile without errors:

```
double* value() {
    return nullptr;
}

double*& function() {
    double* valueVar = value();
    return valueVar;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why? I would've thought they did exactly the same thing, to me the second code just looks redundant.

Comment: Look up l-values vs r-values.

Comment: Even if you make it compile changing to const reference, it still will not work (though compile). You would get reference to a temporary which will be dangled after exit from the function.

Comment: The second example should compile without errors, but with an important warning. (Assuming warnings are enabled, and it's really not a good idea to disable this one.)

Comment: @Slava what is the suggested course of action when you need to return a reference to something returned from a different function?

Comment: You need to store that value in an object (pointer in this case) which lifetime is equal or longer than reference. You may consider static variable, but that is dangerous solution (less dangerous though than returning dangling reference)

Answer (score 4):

`value()` returns pointer by value, what it returns is an rvalue and can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const like `double* &`, so your 1st code snippet doesn't compile.

In the 2nd code snippet you're binding a local object to the reference. `valueVar` is an lvalue and could be bound to the lvalue-reference to non-const, but note that the local object will be destroyed when the function returns, then the returned reference will always be dangled, any dereference on it leads to UB.